# Form Validation On Frontend or Backend Django

Tags: django

I have an HTML form with a date field:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" name="date" autocomplete="off" required>
```

Before submitted the form, I want to ensure that the date that was entered is greater than the current date. If it is older, then I want to show a custom form validation to say something like, "You must enter a date past today.".

Do you suggest I do this validation on the backend or the frontend? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're better off doing in within django forms. The reason is, if you do it in the front-end, you'll have to repeat the code when applying this property elsewhere.

Comment: I see, makes sense. Thank you!!